# How can I transfer service cloud customizations from an Enterprise Developer Sandbox org to an Unlimited Developer Sandbox org?

Tags: deployment, scratch-org

I have created and customized a service console app in our developer sandbox org which is an enterprise edition and want to put it in a scratch org for further customization. After that I would deploy this from scratch org to another sandbox but this time an Unlimited Edition (newly acquired org). Is this possible? What possibly could go wrong?  Please suggest the best way to achieve this path. Any detailed documentation around steps would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can deploy all the customization which you have in scratch org or Enterprise Edition to an unlimited Edition org.But,you need to have all the other dependent metadata in the destination org.

If you are using the VS code to deploy/push the metadata to Scratch org then please refer this [blog](https://techevangel.com/2018/07/26/deploy-retrieve-metadata-using-salesforce-dx-and-vs-code/) for helpful information.